# if $\{x| f(x) \neq g(x))\}$ has zero measure then $\int f = \int g$.

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, riemann-integration

Let $f,g$ be integrable functions in a closed box $B \subset \mathbb R^n$.
Suppose that the set $A = \{x \in B| f(x) \neq g(x)\}$ is negligible. Show that $\int_Bf =\int_B g$

What I tried:

Notice that $B = A \cup (A^c \cap B)$ and that $A \cap (A^c \cap B) = \emptyset$ obviously.

Then $\int_Bf - \int_B g = \int_B f-g = \int_{A}f-g+\int_{A^c \cap B}f-g = \int_{A}f-g$

Now see that $0 = v(A)\inf_{x \in A}(f-g)(x) \leq \int_{A}f-g \leq v(A) \sup_{x \in A}(f-g)(x) =0$ because $v(A) = 0$ since it's negligible, and $f,g$ are integrable on $B$ so we know they are bounded.

**Where is my issue:**

I'm unsure about

$\int_B f-g = \int_{A}f-g+\int_{A^c \cap B}f-g$, I realize it's true when $A,A^c \cap B$ are boxes. If I split a big box into two smaller non intersecting boxes, then the integral on the big box is equal to the sum of the integrals of the two smaller boxes, but is it also true for general shapes?

Is there a way to prove this without resorting to integrals over non boxes?

Comment: Not sure about your tags... I would not tag calculus and I would tag Lebesgue integration instead of Riemann Integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can also prove this in the framework of Riemann integration.

Take $h = f- g$ and

$$A = \{x \in B \,|\, f(x) \neq g(x) \} = \{ x \in B \,|\, h(x) \neq  0\}$$ where $A$
has zero measure.

If $P$ is any partition of $B$ into sub-rectangles (boxes) then any such sub-rectangle $R$ has non-zero content and so must include points $y$ not in A such that $h(y) = 0$.

Thus, $\inf_{x \in R}h(x) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \sup_{x \in R} h(x)$ for each $R \in P$ and the lower and upper Darboux sums satisfy

$$L(P,h) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(P,h), \\ \implies L(P,h) \leqslant \sup_P L(P,h) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \inf_P \,U(P,h) \leqslant U(P,h)$$

However, we are given that $f$ and $g$, and , hence, $h$ are integrable.

Thus,

$$\int_B h = \sup_P L(P,h) \geqslant 0 , \quad \int_B h = \inf_P \,L(P,h) \leqslant 0,$$

which implies

$$\int_Bf - \int_B g = \int_Bh = 0$$

Comment: Why must any such sub rectangle include points not from $A$? How did you use the fact that $A$ has zero measure?

Comment: In Riemann integration over boxes in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we always use partitions where the sub-boxes are of the form $R = [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times \ldots \times [a_n,b_n]$ and each interval is non-empty.  Otherwise $vol(R) = 0$ and it contributes nothing to a Darboux or Rieman sum.  It is impossible for $R \subset A$ since the measure of $R$ is non-zero.  Every partition element has to include points where $h$ is $0$.  This is the easiest proof of this theorem requiring the least amount of measure theory.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, so is $f-g$, so $A=(f-g)^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ is a measurable set. Hence also $A^c\cap B$ is measurable.

Then use the fact that for any integrable function $f$ and partitioning measurable sets $A$ and $B$ we have $f=\chi_Af+\chi_Bf$ and hence $\int f=\int\chi_Af+\chi_Bf=\int\chi_Af+\int\chi_Bf=\int_Af+\int_Bf$.

Here $\chi_A$ denotes the indicator function, which is $1$ in $A$ and $0$ elsewhere.